# how to extract JWT when authorize in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs

My purpose is make a role guard  to verify the permission of user. I trying to extract authorization header to get the role information which is include on JWT. I implemented ***canActivate*** interface to check role of use but i don't know how to get the role info from JWT to verify it.

```
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly _reflector: Reflector) {
  }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const roles = this._reflector.get<UserRole[]>(
      'roles',
      context.getHandler(),
    );

    if (!roles || roles.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }

    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user: InstanceType<User> = request.headers.role;

    // i want to get the role from JWT in here

    const hasRole = () => roles.indexOf(user.role) >= 0;

    if (user && user.role && hasRole()) {
      return true;
    }

    throw new HttpException(
      'You do not have permission (Roles)',
      HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
    );
  }
}
```

I tried extends ***PassportStrategy***, but it can't work together with ***CanActive***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use the `JwtService` from the `JwtModule` and use `jwtService.decode(myJwt)` to get the decoded JWT and get the role from there. The other is to use the built Passport Guard (`AuthGuard`), extend the functionality, and call `super.canActivate(context)` before your custom logic. Store he result and immediately check if the user has passport access before continuing with your custom logic.

```js
// the mention of jwt in the AuthGuard is only needed if not working with defaultStrategy
export class RolesGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  constructor(private readonly _reflector: Reflector) {
    super()
  }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const passportActive = super.canActivate(context);
    if (!passportActivate) {
      throw new HttpException(
        'You do not have permission (Roles)',
        HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
      );
    }
    const roles = this._reflector.get<UserRole[]>(
      'roles',
      context.getHandler(),
    );

    if (!roles || roles.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }

    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    // this should come from passport
    const user: InstanceType<User> = request.user;

    // i want to get the role from JWT in here

    const hasRole = () => roles.indexOf(user.role) >= 0;

    if (user && user.role && hasRole()) {
      return true;
    }

    throw new HttpException(
      'You do not have permission (Roles)',
      HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i used first suggest, inject JwtService to handle. It worked for me.